# OnOptionsItemSelected Not called when NavigationRoot has happened

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I've got a problem I am unable to solve.
I have a Xamarin Forms app with the current code:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));

        Toolbar toolbar = this.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        if (item.ItemId == 16908332)
        {
             //stuff going on
        }
    }
}
```

Which works correctly.

However, my flow is like this:

- Login
- Mainscreen (with NavigationPage)
- Detailscreen (with NavigationPage, in here you go back to mainscreen with back)

The login will be stored. Which is exactly what is required. However. When I am logging in, I reset my root navigation to the mainscreen. If you are already logged in, this will not happen and you are directed right away to Mainscreen.

If I am already logged in, evertything works fine.

OnOptionsItemSelected Is called accordingly.
If the login screen is set first (or I log off and on again) OnOptionsItemSelected is not called (anymore).

I am not that familiair with Xamarin and I an unaware how to fix this.

What can I do?

Comment: Where is the function `OnOptionsItemSelected `  used in your project? If is it convinient for you,could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can help you better?

Comment: It is used for validating the back button in navigation page (as everyone uses it for).

Comment: If is it convinient for you,could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can help you better?